# alternate char match in string

Tags: c, string

Alternate code character should be same can you tell me how to correct my program as one test case shown by me wanted to executed exactly like that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int T, i;
  char ticketnumber[102];
  scanf("%d", &T);

  while (T--) {
    bool flag = false;
    scanf("%s", ticketnumber);
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(ticketnumber); i++) {
      if ((ticketnumber[i] == ticketnumber[i + 2])
          && (ticketnumber[i] != ticketnumber[i + 1])) {
        flag = true;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }

    if (flag != false) {
      printf("YES");
    } else {
      printf("NO");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Necessary: I/P:

```
3

CFCFCF

CRGHIT

CGIRST
```

O/P:

```
YES

NO

NO
```

Alternate code character should be same can you tell me how to correct my program?

If alternate char of string contains in whole length of string then we need to print "yes" else "No".

Comment: I/P:6
GIFST
GRTET
GRIST
GSGSGI
GIGIGI
FGITRE

Comment: You could try starting the loop with `i = 2` and compare `arr[i] == arr[i-2]` and `arr[i] != arr[i-1]`... That way the loop will end when you reach the last character (instead of checking beyond the end of the string.) (PS: `flag != false` would be simpler are `flag == true`, or even simply `flag`....)

Comment: When `i` becomes equal to `strlen(ticketnumber) - 1` the access `ticketnumber[i + 2]` reads a character **after** the string.

Comment: OT: Putting `strlen(ticketnumber)` in the loop condition may result in bad performance as `strlen` may be called several times. Read it into a variable **before** the loop

Answer (score 0):

On the final iteration of the `for` loop, `ticketnumber[i + 2]` attempts to read the character positioned one past the null-terminating byte, potentially invoking [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) if this extends beyond the end of the array.

As is, `flag` is set to `true` upon completing a single iteration. This pattern will yield incorrect results for strings that fail the test after the first iteration, as `flag` is not set to `false` in this event.

With a problem like this, it is generally better to assume the data will pass the test (`true`), and end the procedure early when it does not (`false`).

As pointed out in the comments, instead of looking forward in the string, start iterating from the third position and look behind at the previous two positions.

There is a base case to consider: the empty string.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

bool is_alternating(const char *s, size_t len)
{
    if (0 == len)
        return false; /* is an empty string alternating or not? */

    if (2 == len)
        return s[0] != s[1];

    for (size_t i = 2; i < len; i++)
        if (s[i] != s[i - 2] || s[i] == s[i - 1])
            return false;

    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[512];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
        size_t length = strcspn(buffer, "\r\n");
        buffer[length] = 0;
        printf("%s = %s\n", buffer,
                is_alternating(buffer, length) ? "YES" : "NO");
    }
}
```

Input:

```
CFCFCF
CRGHIT
CGIRST
```

Output:

```
CFCFCF = YES
CRGHIT = NO
CGIRST = NO
```